# error to use multiple AjaxFileUpload control in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, ajax, asp.net-ajax

Problem is :

In Default page i have two AjaxFileUpload controls and i done code as per the rule, when i click upload in both upload button one by one image will be stored in only one folder 
(i.e. same first folder).

**page code is given below**

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<asp:ScriptManager ID="sm1" runat="server">
</asp:ScriptManager>
<div>
    <asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" />
    <ajaxToolkit:AjaxFileUpload ID="AjaxFileUpload1" runat="server" OnUploadComplete="FileUploadCompleteEvent1"
        ThrobberID="Image1" Width="400" />
</div>
<div>
    <asp:Image ID="Image2" runat="server" />
    <ajaxToolkit:AjaxFileUpload ID="AjaxFileUpload2" runat="server" ThrobberID="Image2"
        OnUploadComplete="FileUploadCompleteEvent2" Width="400" />
</div>    
</form>
```

and Default.aspx.cs is

```
    protected void FileUploadCompleteEvent1(object o,AjaxControlToolkit.AjaxFileUploadEventArgs e)
   {    
      string file = Server.MapPath("~/i/") + e.FileName;
      AjaxFileUpload1.SaveAs(file);
    }
    protected void FileUploadCompleteEvent2(object o, AjaxControlToolkit.AjaxFileUploadEventArgs eve)
    {
        string file = Server.MapPath("~/i1/") + eve.FileName;
        AjaxFileUpload2.SaveAs(file);
    }
```

I want to store these files in separate folders (i and i1), I have attached the code that i am using.

Comment: Actually i dont see anything wrong in your code.

Comment: image store only on one folder (i) , instead of folder(i) and folder (i1)

Comment: hello any one has answer of this question ???

Comment: i am facing same error, i think that is bug remains in Ajax Codeplex Control tool by Microsoft.